# Convert string in array form to actual array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, string

I have a text file in this format:

```
[[Line1TextA,[Lat,Long]], [Line1TextB,[Lat,Long]], ...]
[[Line2TextC,[Lat,Long]], [Line2TextD,[Lat,Long]], ...]
.
.
.
```

I am parsing a text file (done) and I want to convert strings in array format into actual array and store them as a variable to use.

I tried to use JSON.parse, as suggested here: [Convert string containing arrays to actual arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191171) but I couldn't get it to work (syntax errors). Here is my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/5yz95ktg/

`var myStr = '[[Line1TextA,[Lat,Long]], [Line1TextB,[Lat,Long]]]'`

- `var myArr = JSON.parse(myStr);`
- `var myArr = JSON.parse("[" + myStr + "]");`

**Edit:**

```
function readFile(query) {
    $.get('file.txt', function(data) {
        var lines = data.split("\n");    
        for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (lines[i].indexOf(query) > -1) { // Found a match
                var myArr = JSON.parse(lines[i]); // #NOT WORKING
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting when using `JSON.parse`. Add actual sample array.

Comment: Console shows "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token". It is provided inside jsfiddle, but I will add it to the OP too.

Comment: Are the array values wrapped in quotes. If you directly put the array from file does it run?

Comment: You need to wrap the array values with quotes. https://jsfiddle.net/5yz95ktg/3/

Comment: provide demo with full example including csv parsing. Too many unknowns considering that the current demo works fine

Comment: @Tushar The sample data is how it is inside the file (without quotes). is there any other way than to add quotes to every element? I have like 10k elements total in 150 lines.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Can split each line by csv delimiter into array. Suggest using a parsing library like Papa Parse

Comment: @charlietfl I have already restructured my csv: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917717

Comment: Save yourself the headaches ... http://papaparse.com/

Comment: I tried PapaParse with this example, but I couldn't get it to work.  www.joyofdata.de/blog/parsing-local-csv-file-with-javascript-papa-parse/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to make sure they are strings:

```
var myStr = '[[Line1TextA,[Lat,Long]], [Line1TextB,[Lat,Long]]]'
//-------------^
```

So change it to:

```
var str = '[["Line1TextA",["Lat","Long"]],["Line1TextB",["Lat","Long"]]]'
```

Also make sure you use `"` inside the JSON, as `'` is invalid.

Comment: You were the first to actually post an answer (instead of comments), so picking yours as the correct answer. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity's sake, Javascript has two types of arrays: numeric and associative. This is similar to other languages but implemented a bit differently. In reality, arrays are really objects where numeric arrays are in an array object and associative are a plain object.

Here are the two syntaxes:

```
var numericArr = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 42, false];
// numericArr[0] === 'foo'
// numericArr[3] === 42

var assocArr = {'type': 'foo', 'example': 'bar'};
// This can also be written as {type: 'foo'} (keys don't need quotes)
// assocArr['example'] === 'bar'
```

These arrays can be nested as well, like so:

```
var mixedArr = {data: ['foo', 'bar'], success: false};
```

So in your case, the named arrays will need to have curly brackets surrounding them eg.

```
var myStr = '[{"Line1TextA":["Lat","Long"]}, {"Line1TextB":["Lat","Long"]}]'
```

Notice also the quotes surrounding the array keys. You'll need that if you would like to JSON parse the data.

If you are not in a position to rewrite the data that is stored in your files, as long as it's in a consistent format you can use something like regex to do your string manipulation to correctly format the data.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use regex to place the quotes, then use JSON.parse() to parse the properly-formatted json into an array.

```
var myStr = '[[Line1TextA,[Lat,Long]], [Line1TextB,[Lat,Long]]]';

var json = myStr.replace(/([^\[\],\s]+)/g, '"$&"');
var array = JSON.parse(json);
```

Working examle: https://jsfiddle.net/397owg7q/

You might need to change the regex a bit, this only works if your data doesn't have whitespace or quotes.

Comment: I was able to easily change the regex since I restructured the csv to begin with.